# Non-disclosure agreement for an open source project

Tags: licensing

I work on a third-party open source project (partly GPL 3, partly Apache 2).

I don't want to disclose my changes right away (but publish them in the future).

Is it legal to require a hired worker whom I want to show my code to sign a non-disclosure agreement for my changes? Would it contradict to the license? (My main changes are in an Apache 2 licensed file.)

Comment: I think it should be clarified if you are the author of that "third-party" open source project under GNU GPL (I think you are not), AND if you have any intention to distribute that software to somebody public external, like a customer etc. (I think yes). That could be important to give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 5):

I am not a lawyer, so verify this yourself.

See the GPL FAQ:
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic

> **Does the GPL require that source code of modified versions be posted to the public?**
>
> The GPL does not require you to release your modified version, or any part of it. You are free to make modifications and use them privately, without ever releasing them. This applies to organizations (including companies), too; an organization can make a modified version and use it internally without ever releasing it outside the organization.
>
> But if you release the modified version to the public in some way, the GPL requires you to make the modified source code available to the program's users, under the GPL.
>
> Thus, the GPL gives permission to release the modified program in certain ways, and not in other ways; but the decision of whether to release it is up to you.

As long as you do not let it escape, you don’t have to provide the sources.

And the GPL does not evict your own copyright on your changes, thus it should be possible to exert your copyright and demand non-disclosure, but only for the bits you personally hold the copyright of.
You could state that the modified version is a proprietary modification and your changes are covered under "all rights reserved", thus prevent re-distribution of your changes.

If the co-worker leaks the code they perform a copyright infringement, and the code won’t be properly “released”. See https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#StolenCopy

On the other hand, I don’t understand why you would need such an NDA for changes to a GPL-licensed program/library. It sounds like you want to work against the intended purpose of the license. But this is up to you, so I won’t question it further.

Comment: “if your coworker leaks it you have to release your changes” – no, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#StolenCopy>. It is up to the copyright holder to decide whether the material is published, they are just have to follow the GPL's terms if they decide to publish. Leaks or other illegal means violate that copyright, and don't give anyone rights to the illegally obtained material.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll edit the answer

Comment: *"On the other hand, I don’t understand why you would need such an NDA for changes to a GPL-licensed program/library."* - first mover advantage. Say, my company developed a device which came with modified Linux kernel. Not publishing the code early would keep the new product a secret until it is ready to be sold/announced.

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable. Thanks for explaining the reasoning behind it

Answer (score 4):

This frequently asked question seems to describe your need:

> **Does the GPL allow me to develop a modified version under a nondisclosure agreement?**
>
> **Yes**. For instance, you can accept a contract to develop changes and agree not to release your changes until the client says ok. This
> is permitted because in this case no GPL-covered code is being
> distributed under an NDA.
>
> You can also release your changes to the client under the GPL, but agree not to release them to anyone else unless the client says ok. In
> this case, too, no GPL-covered code is being distributed under an NDA,
> or under any additional restrictions.
>
> The GPL would give the client the right to redistribute your version. In this scenario, the client will probably choose not to
> exercise that right, but does have the right.
>
> ― https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#DevelopChangesUnderNDA

Here some more facets:

- [Does the GPL allow me to develop a modified version under a nondisclosure agreement?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#DevelopChangesUnderNDA)
- [Does the GPL allow me to distribute copies under a nondisclosure agreement?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#DoesTheGPLAllowNDA)
- [Does the GPL allow me to distribute a modified or beta version under a nondisclosure agreement?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#DoesTheGPLAllowModNDA)